# DESC LIMIT doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql

I made a CMS with a news system but it doesn't work. I wanted to set a `DESC LIMIT` on it to `3` but it doesn't work.

So, my question is, what is wrong in this code? I can't see the fault. I tried different things but they all don't work.

```
<?php

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY article_id DESC LIMIT 3");
    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
        if ($numrows > 0){
            while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query) ){
                $id = $row['article_id'];
                $name = $row['article_title'];
                $msg = $row['samenvatting'];
            }
        } 

include_once('cms/includes/connection.php');
include_once('cms/includes/article.php');

$article = new Article;
$articles = $article->fetch_all();
?>

    <div class="container">

        <tr>
            <?php foreach ($articles as $article){ ?>

                    <h4><?php echo $article['article_title']; ?></h4>

                <p><?php echo $article['samenvatting']; ?><br/>

                <a href="article.php?id=<?php echo $article['article_id']; ?>"><small>Lees meer</small> - 

                <small>
                    Gepost op <?php echo date('j M Y', $article['article_timestamp']); ?>
                </small></a></p>

            <?php } ?>
        </tr>
    </div>
```

Comment: What doesn't work? What error do you get? What are you expecting? What are you getting?

Comment: It just doesnt work it doesnt show only 3 but 10 recent news posts.

Comment: `desc limit` is SQL, not PHP

Comment: You're not even doing something with the variables you set in the while loop after your sql query. You're printing something from the articles object...

Comment: i'm getting the rows with em

Comment: Your structure makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `mysql_query` at the top has no effect, because you don't use the result anywhere.

Your result set is not limited, because you say

```
$articles = $article->fetch_all();
```

furthermore, you show everything with

```
foreach ($articles as $article){
```

If you want to limit the result set, you must do so when doing the `fetch` or you track the rows in the loop and stop as soon as you've shown the desired three rows.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL a `LIMIT` does not have a direction.

I think you're getting confused with `ORDER BY`

With `ORDER BY` you order a column, in the direction of your choice.

E.g.

```
SELECT x FROM y ORDER BY x DESC
```

So, if for example, `x` was an integer type, and you wanted the highest 5 values, you would run:

```
SELECT x FROM y ORDER BY x DESC LIMIT 5
```

Comment: What doesn't? I haven't given you a working example, it's a syntax example.